# Replacing a column of data based on whether datapoints from 2 other columns are same/similar

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, loops, dictionary

For context I'm on python version 3.7.4 and I'm new to this so please have mercy on me in the comments D:

I have 2 excel sheets, 1 which has incorrect and wrongly formatted data points and the other which has all the correct data points neatly stored. I am trying to replace sheet 1 column 2 with sheet 2 column 2 only if column 1 from both sheet match. The issue is that in sheet 1 column 1 there are multiple cells with the same contents. assuming that there are no errors with formatting, how can I go about doing this?

```
#dummy data
#df1 is the spotty dataframe
df1_sheet1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
df1_sheet2 = [A, B, C, D, D, D, F, E]

#df2 is the correct dataframe
df2_sheet1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df2_sheet2 = [A, b, C, D, E]
```